# Where is the best place to put the company logo on this banner?

Tags: print-design, page-layout

I want to know where is the best place to put the company logo; top centre, bottom of text or where?. I can move the text up or down. So, I need your suggestions. I plane to add flat colour design near the bottom of the banner. Image is attached.

[image: image of banner]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is relative on where that banner is.

If it is an **internal company campain**, or banner, everyone should know it is refering to the company they are working in. So it dosen't matter.

If it is an external people the ones that are reading it, the "correct" visual syntax would be put the company logo (or name) before the afirmation "our".

This is question is opinion based. So I'm answering that you need to read the syntax of the campain.

---

Hi I'm am Rafael...

Bla, bla.

Name on top => presentation, branding, informal.

---

Dear company members...

bla bla bla.

Best regards: Rafael.

Name on bottom => signature, formal.

---

So... you need to make your choices.

Comment: it's an internal company

Comment: should it be before or after the text?